# Run Camunda Operate dockerized behind an nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, camunda, zeebe

I've successfully deployed dockerized versions camunda operate, zeebe broker, and elasticsearch.  I can access the web ui for camunda operate at localhost:8080.  I need to put these behind an existing nginx reverse proxy.  My first attempt was to do:

```
location /operate/ {
    proxy_pass http://operate:8080/;    
}
```

Operate is the name of the docker container, and the nginx container is running within the same network.  Navigating to https://localhost/operate shows me a blank page with the Camunda Operate title showing.  What seems to be happening is the initial /operate call is proxied successfully, but subsequent calls to static resources go to https://localhost/static/some-script.js instead of https://localhost/operate/static/some-script.js

I thought specifying /operate/ instead of /operate in the nginx location would do the trick, but no luck.  Any clarification would be appreciated!

Comment: Seems more related to nginx configuration and it is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426844/2165134

Comment: I've tried that suggestion but it doesn't seem to work.  I'm wondering if the operate web app itself is using non-relative URLs or something so it doesn't respect the /operate/ portion of the current path.

Comment: It seems I'm running in to an issue similar to here:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html

The URLs being used by the webapp are not relative, so I need to add location rules for /css, /js/ /img etc. in my nginx configuration.  This does work but it's not ideal since I can't use those paths for any other applications I'd like to put behind a proxy.

Comment: @Rudy have you find any solution for this, i'm also having same problem