# How do I pass a subpath with nginx proxy_pass selectively?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, proxypass

So I want to use Nginx `proxy_pass` to reroute my urls, which may or may not have subpaths, to the same port.

For example, `.../users` should be redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/users`, but, another url of the form `.../users/foo/bar` should also be redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/foo/bar`.

I was able to achieve just the /users implementation, but as soon as I type /users/foo/bar, I get a 404 Not Found error.

So far my configuration looks like the following:

```
location ^~ /users {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/users;
}
```

I have tried the various solutions from:
[nginx proxy pass subpaths not redirected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423414/nginx-proxy-pass-subpaths-not-redirected)

Comment: I think you want something like `proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8080$request_uri;`

Comment: @Deancoakley how exactly can I use that? I have tried searching online for a way that matches my need but to no avail.